# How to eliminate letter?

Tags: ruby

I want a string which eliminates every "x, X". For example Xylophone -> ylophone, Xbox -> bo.
This is my recent code:

```
class String
 def xaway
 s = self.split("")
 return ( s - ["xX"] ).join
 end
end
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `str.delete('xX')`?

Comment: @Stefan : May I suggest that you add this as answer?

Comment: @kyle : _What is wrong?_ : Your array `s` does not contain an element consisting of the string `xX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is wrong?

Splitting the string by `""` returns an array of characters, e.g.:

```
"Xbox".split("")
#=> ["X", "b", "o", "x"]
```

And [`Array#-`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#2D-method) expects an array of elements to remove. But if you pass `["Xx"]` it tries to remove the element `"Xx"` which doesn't exist in the array:

```
["X", "b", "o", "x"] - ["Xx"]
#=> ["X", "b", "o", "x"]
```

What you want is `["X", "x"]`:

```
["X", "b", "o", "x"] - ["X", "x"]
#=> ["b", "o"]
```

The whole code:

```
class String
  def xaway
     (split("") - ["X", "x"]).join
  end
end
```

A little more concise:

```
class String
  def xaway
     (chars - %w[X x]).join
  end
end
```

Or, using [`String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#delete-method):

```
class String
  def xaway
    delete("Xx")
  end
end
```

Note that you shouldn't modify Ruby's core classes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using the [tr](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr) function, depending on your usage requirements:

```
class String
  def xaway
    tr("xX","")
  end
end
```